# linux/module.h No such file or Directory

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, ubuntu-10.04, adhoc

For my thesis I am creating a Manet using the protocol ARAN. To install the protocol I'm using [this manual](http://prisms.cs.umass.edu/arand/install.php), but the first step, the creation of trace_route, I received errors such as:

```
-linux/module.h: No such file or directory

-linux/procs_Fs: No such file or directory

-linux/skbuff: No such file or directory
```

I searched the web and found out that the problem is in the headers, but I do not find the solution ...

P.S. I am using **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS** Kernel 2.6.33 recompiled

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing the Linux kernel headers which allow you to compile code against the Linux kernel.

To install just the headers in **Ubuntu**:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

To install the entire Linux kernel source in **Ubuntu**:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-source
```

*Note that you should use the kernel headers that match the kernel you are running.*

Answer (score 3):

```
**/*source file name is basic.c */**

#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
/*MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");*/
static int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
}
module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

=====================================

## now make file for ubuntu

/*at first type on ur terminal that $(uname -r) then u will get the version..
that is using on ur system */

```
obj-m +=basic.o

KDIR =//usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-44-generic

all:
 $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
 rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

================================================

## **To run the code**

```
$sudo insmode basic.ko
$dmesg
u will get the output
$sudo rmmod basic.ko
$dmesg
```

Comment: Nice working example of the example in 'Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition' - Thanks.

Comment: Thanks sir @SimonPeverett