# Can't find header <linux/kfifo.h>

Tags: c, linux, header, kernel

On my linux (*3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu*), I include kfifo header via:

```
#include <linux/kfifo.h>
```

According to [linux-module-h-no-such-file-or-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919512/), I also installed kernel header via:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

And the file is located at:

> /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-38/include/linux/kfifo.h

But, when compile, still can't find the header:

> kfifo_test.c:5:25: fatal error: linux/kfifo.h: No such file or directory

Any help? Thanks.

---

### @Update

It seems gcc didn't find the header file.

When compile via:

`gcc -I "/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-38/include/" kfifo_test.c`

It found `linux/kfifo.h`, but the `asm/linkage.h` can't be found, which is used by `linux/kfifo.h` I guess.

> In file included from
>   /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-38/include/linux/kernel.h:6:0,
>   from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-38/include/linux/kfifo.h:53,
>   from kfifo_test.c:7: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-38/include/linux/linkage.h:7:25: fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory

Then, add another `-I` option, when compile via:

```
gcc -I"/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-38/include/" -I"/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-38/arch/x86/include/" kfifo_test.c
```

The `asm/linkage.h` is found, but again recursively more error occurs. ( e.g `fatal error: asm/early_ioremap.h: No such file or directory`).

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Comment: @fluter I compile it via `gcc -Wall kfifo_test.c`

Comment: The file is supposed to be used with kernel code, you will need make a kernel module for that.

Comment: @fluter Ok, so it should not be used outside of kernel ?

Comment: That's right, it's not for user space application

Comment: @fluter Ok, I see.